# How to send EOF indicator in console

Tags: python, c#

For example, in C# Visual Studio if I input key combination Ctrl + Z it sends null to program and i use it in sentinel controlled loops for example in C#:

```
int total = 0;
string myInput = Console.ReadLine();
while (myInput != null)
{
     total++;
     myInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Does this exist in python?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this in Python is to iterate over the input:

```
import sys

total = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    total += 1

print(total)
```

Or, if you really only want to count lines, you can write this shorter as

```
import sys

print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))
```

This is using a so-called [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Answer (score 0):

We can control it by EOF error exception, Simply type Ctrl + Z.

```
s = input()
i = 0
try:
    while (True):
        i += 1
        s = input()
except EOFError:
    print(i)
```